# Google maps API : V2 : Custom infowindow with bindInfoWindowHtml

Tags: google-maps

The API documentation gave me hopes last night with "bindInfoWindowHtml".
But it doesn't seem to replace the default infoWindow, even when you provide your own class etc.

I have tried using other ideas like the **labeledmarker**. But it doesn't support draggable markers. Hence can't use it in my application.

Here is the sample code which shows the info. window inside, the original bubble.
Isn't there a way to override that window as well !

`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .infoWindowCustomClass
    {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: #CAEE96;
        color: #666;
    }
</style>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key="" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
  {
        // Create our "tiny" marker icon
        var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
        blueIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";

        // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
        markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(33.968064,-83.377047), 13);

        markerOptions.title = "fart";
        var point = new GLatLng(33.968064,-83.377047);
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        var tempName = document.getElementById("infoWindowCustom");
        marker.bindInfoWindowHtml(tempName);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
}

</script>`
```

And here is the DIV -

`<DIV id="infoWindowCustom" name="infoWindowCustom" class="infoWindowCustomClass">

Name : <TEXTAREA NAME="nameID" ID="nameID" ROWS="2" COLS="25"></TEXTAREA>

Comments : <TEXTAREA NAME="commentsID" ID="commentsID" ROWS="4" COLS="25"></TEXTAREA>

    </DIV>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it as below -

Instead of binding it as above, I take the lang/lats and launch a div at that place.
That seems to work just fine.